# Why does linking with g++ or ld not work (multiple undefined references), if I try to create a library with swig (c++ to c#)?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, g++, swig

I want to create a dynamic library (on windows with c++). I have two files to compile and link. The generation of the necessary files with swig and compilation with g++ work fine.

```
PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\swig\bla\include> swig -csharp HelloWorld.i

PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\swig\bla\include> g++ -fPIC -c HelloWorld_wrap.c -I C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\include -I C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\include\c++\12.2.0 -I C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.2.0 -I C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32

PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\swig\bla\include> g++ -fPIC -c HelloWorld.cpp
```

After that there are `HelloWorld.o` and `HelloWorldWrap.o` in the `include` directory and I want to link them with g++. That doesnt work:

```
PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\swig\bla\include> g++ -shared HelloWorld.o HelloWorld_wrap.o -o libHelloWorld.dll
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld.o: in function `Foo::HelloWorld::GetHello[abi:cxx11]()':
helloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o: in function `CSharp_helloWorld':
helloWorld_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `helloWorld[abi:cxx11]()'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)':
helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx11char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc[_ZN9__gnu_cxx11char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc]+0x67): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)':
helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC2IS3_EEPKcRKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC5IS3_EEPKcRKS3_]+0xb9): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld.o: in function `void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x96): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xbb): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long)'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xf0): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long)'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: helloWorld.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x13b): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using `ld` instead of `g++ -shared` does not work either

```
PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\swig\bla\include> ld -G HelloWorld_wrap.o HelloWorld.o -o libHelloWorld.o
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `helloWorld[abi:cxx11]()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `malloc'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `memmove'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x1f8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.text+0x217): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld_wrap.o:HelloWorld_wra:(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt11char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc[_ZNSt11char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc]+0x2b): undefined reference to `strlen'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_Alloc_hiderD1Ev[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_Alloc_hiderD1Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_]+0x24): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_]+0x36): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(char*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_]+0x4c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_]+0x99): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.xdata$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1IS3_EEPKcRKS3_+0x10): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tagEN6_GuardD1Ev[_ZZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tagEN6_GuardD1Ev]+0x23): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.xdata$_ZZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tagEN6_GuardD1Ev+0xc): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x44): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long long&, unsigned long long)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x53): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data(char*)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x63): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long long)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x79): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data()'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x96): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xac): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char const*, char const*)'
C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\ld.exe: HelloWorld.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPKcEEvT_S8_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xc4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long long)'
```

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/winlibs_mingw_gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/r/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=  [...]
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)

ld -v
GNU ld (Binutils for MinGW-W64 x86_64, built by Brecht Sanders) 2.40
```

The HelloWorld_wrap.cxx file:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 4.0.2
 *
 * This file is not intended to be easily readable and contains a number of
 * coding conventions designed to improve portability and efficiency. Do not make
 * changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify the SWIG
 * interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


#ifndef SWIGCSHARP
#define SWIGCSHARP
#endif



#ifdef __cplusplus
/* SwigValueWrapper is described in swig.swg */
template<typename T> class SwigValueWrapper {
  struct SwigMovePointer {
    T *ptr;
    SwigMovePointer(T *p) : ptr(p) { }
    ~SwigMovePointer() { delete ptr; }
    SwigMovePointer& operator=(SwigMovePointer& rhs) { T* oldptr = ptr; ptr = 0; delete oldptr; ptr = rhs.ptr; rhs.ptr = 0; return *this; }
  } pointer;
  SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
  SwigValueWrapper(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
public:
  SwigValueWrapper() : pointer(0) { }
  SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const T& t) { SwigMovePointer tmp(new T(t)); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
  operator T&() const { return *pointer.ptr; }
  T *operator&() { return pointer.ptr; }
};

template <typename T> T SwigValueInit() {
  return T();
}
#endif

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  This section contains generic SWIG labels for method/variable
 *  declarations/attributes, and other compiler dependent labels.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* template workaround for compilers that cannot correctly implement the C++ standard */
#ifndef SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR
# if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && (__SUNPRO_CC <= 0x560)
#  define SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR template
# elif defined(__HP_aCC)
/* Needed even with `aCC -AA' when `aCC -V' reports HP ANSI C++ B3910B A.03.55 */
/* If we find a maximum version that requires this, the test would be __HP_aCC <= 35500 for A.03.55 */
#  define SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR template
# else
#  define SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR
# endif
#endif

/* inline attribute */
#ifndef SWIGINLINE
# if defined(__cplusplus) || (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__))
#   define SWIGINLINE inline
# else
#   define SWIGINLINE
# endif
#endif

/* attribute recognised by some compilers to avoid 'unused' warnings */
#ifndef SWIGUNUSED
# if defined(__GNUC__)
#   if !(defined(__cplusplus)) || (__GNUC__ > 3 || (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 4))
#     define SWIGUNUSED __attribute__ ((__unused__))
#   else
#     define SWIGUNUSED
#   endif
# elif defined(__ICC)
#   define SWIGUNUSED __attribute__ ((__unused__))
# else
#   define SWIGUNUSED
# endif
#endif

#ifndef SWIG_MSC_UNSUPPRESS_4505
# if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   pragma warning(disable : 4505) /* unreferenced local function has been removed */
# endif
#endif

#ifndef SWIGUNUSEDPARM
# ifdef __cplusplus
#   define SWIGUNUSEDPARM(p)
# else
#   define SWIGUNUSEDPARM(p) p SWIGUNUSED
# endif
#endif

/* internal SWIG method */
#ifndef SWIGINTERN
# define SWIGINTERN static SWIGUNUSED
#endif

/* internal inline SWIG method */
#ifndef SWIGINTERNINLINE
# define SWIGINTERNINLINE SWIGINTERN SWIGINLINE
#endif

/* exporting methods */
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#  if (__GNUC__ >= 4) || (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 4)
#    ifndef GCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY
#      define GCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef SWIGEXPORT
# if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#   if defined(STATIC_LINKED)
#     define SWIGEXPORT
#   else
#     define SWIGEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#   endif
# else
#   if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(GCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY)
#     define SWIGEXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#   else
#     define SWIGEXPORT
#   endif
# endif
#endif

/* calling conventions for Windows */
#ifndef SWIGSTDCALL
# if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#   define SWIGSTDCALL __stdcall
# else
#   define SWIGSTDCALL
# endif
#endif

/* Deal with Microsoft's attempt at deprecating C standard runtime functions */
#if !defined(SWIG_NO_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE) && defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE)
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#endif

/* Deal with Microsoft's attempt at deprecating methods in the standard C++ library */
#if !defined(SWIG_NO_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE) && defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE)
# define _SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#endif

/* Deal with Apple's deprecated 'AssertMacros.h' from Carbon-framework */
#if defined(__APPLE__) && !defined(__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES)
# define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
#endif

/* Intel's compiler complains if a variable which was never initialised is
 * cast to void, which is a common idiom which we use to indicate that we
 * are aware a variable isn't used.  So we just silence that warning.
 * See: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/192 for more discussion.
 */
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
# pragma warning disable 592
#endif


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* Support for throwing C# exceptions from C/C++. There are two types: 
 * Exceptions that take a message and ArgumentExceptions that take a message and a parameter name. */
typedef enum {
  SWIG_CSharpApplicationException,
  SWIG_CSharpArithmeticException,
  SWIG_CSharpDivideByZeroException,
  SWIG_CSharpIndexOutOfRangeException,
  SWIG_CSharpInvalidCastException,
  SWIG_CSharpInvalidOperationException,
  SWIG_CSharpIOException,
  SWIG_CSharpNullReferenceException,
  SWIG_CSharpOutOfMemoryException,
  SWIG_CSharpOverflowException,
  SWIG_CSharpSystemException
} SWIG_CSharpExceptionCodes;

typedef enum {
  SWIG_CSharpArgumentException,
  SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException,
  SWIG_CSharpArgumentOutOfRangeException
} SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCodes;

typedef void (SWIGSTDCALL* SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t)(const char *);
typedef void (SWIGSTDCALL* SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t)(const char *, const char *);

typedef struct {
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionCodes code;
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t callback;
} SWIG_CSharpException_t;

typedef struct {
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCodes code;
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t callback;
} SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgument_t;

static SWIG_CSharpException_t SWIG_csharp_exceptions[] = {
  { SWIG_CSharpApplicationException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpArithmeticException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpDivideByZeroException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpIndexOutOfRangeException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpInvalidCastException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpInvalidOperationException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpIOException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpNullReferenceException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpOutOfMemoryException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpOverflowException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpSystemException, NULL }
};

static SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgument_t SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[] = {
  { SWIG_CSharpArgumentException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException, NULL },
  { SWIG_CSharpArgumentOutOfRangeException, NULL }
};

static void SWIGUNUSED SWIG_CSharpSetPendingException(SWIG_CSharpExceptionCodes code, const char *msg) {
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t callback = SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpApplicationException].callback;
  if ((size_t)code < sizeof(SWIG_csharp_exceptions)/sizeof(SWIG_CSharpException_t)) {
    callback = SWIG_csharp_exceptions[code].callback;
  }
  callback(msg);
}

static void SWIGUNUSED SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionArgument(SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCodes code, const char *msg, const char *param_name) {
  SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t callback = SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[SWIG_CSharpArgumentException].callback;
  if ((size_t)code < sizeof(SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument)/sizeof(SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgument_t)) {
    callback = SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[code].callback;
  }
  callback(msg, param_name);
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_HelloWorld(
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t applicationCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t arithmeticCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t divideByZeroCallback, 
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t indexOutOfRangeCallback, 
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t invalidCastCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t invalidOperationCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t ioCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t nullReferenceCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t outOfMemoryCallback, 
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t overflowCallback, 
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionCallback_t systemCallback) {
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpApplicationException].callback = applicationCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpArithmeticException].callback = arithmeticCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpDivideByZeroException].callback = divideByZeroCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpIndexOutOfRangeException].callback = indexOutOfRangeCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpInvalidCastException].callback = invalidCastCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpInvalidOperationException].callback = invalidOperationCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpIOException].callback = ioCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpNullReferenceException].callback = nullReferenceCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpOutOfMemoryException].callback = outOfMemoryCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpOverflowException].callback = overflowCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions[SWIG_CSharpSystemException].callback = systemCallback;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL SWIGRegisterExceptionArgumentCallbacks_HelloWorld(
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t argumentCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t argumentNullCallback,
                                                SWIG_CSharpExceptionArgumentCallback_t argumentOutOfRangeCallback) {
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[SWIG_CSharpArgumentException].callback = argumentCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException].callback = argumentNullCallback;
  SWIG_csharp_exceptions_argument[SWIG_CSharpArgumentOutOfRangeException].callback = argumentOutOfRangeCallback;
}


/* Callback for returning strings to C# without leaking memory */
typedef char * (SWIGSTDCALL* SWIG_CSharpStringHelperCallback)(const char *);
static SWIG_CSharpStringHelperCallback SWIG_csharp_string_callback = NULL;


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL SWIGRegisterStringCallback_HelloWorld(SWIG_CSharpStringHelperCallback callback) {
  SWIG_csharp_string_callback = callback;
}


/* Contract support */

#define SWIG_contract_assert(nullreturn, expr, msg) if (!(expr)) {SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionArgument(SWIG_CSharpArgumentOutOfRangeException, msg, ""); return nullreturn; } else


#include "Foo/HelloWorld/api.h"
#include "Foo/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.h"
#include <string>
std::string helloWorld();


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_helloWorld() {
  void * jresult ;
  std::string result;
  
  result = helloWorld();
  jresult = new std::string((const std::string &)result); 
  return jresult;
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The HelloWorld.cpp file

```
#include "Foo/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.h"

namespace Foo::HelloWorld {

  std::string GetHello() {
    return "Hello World";
  }

}  // namespace Foo::HelloWorld
```

I tried solving the error by adding the c++ libraries `-I C:\winlibs_mingw_gcc\include\c++\12.2.0` to the compiler input, but that did not work.

Comment: It is not supposed to work. Use `g++` rather tban `ld`. If an invocation with `g++` at the front doesn't work, ask a question about *that* invocation and provide error messages produced by *that* invocation.

Comment: @n.m. I added the error messages after using g++. It still does not work and the error messages are similar: "undefined reference" again...
But why is it not supposed to work with ld directly?

Comment: It is not supposed to work because this is how g++ is designed. g++ calls ld with all the right flags. You are not expected to know them. They may or may not be specific for each gcc installation, version etc etc.

Comment: Now why you are getting the errors you are getting with g++ at the front I don't know. They are definitely unexpected. Can you create a simple toy dll without swig? `g++ -fPIC --shared -o toy_example.dll toy_example.cpp` should Just Work. Have `toy_example.cpp` contain a simple function that prints an std::string to std::cout.

Comment: @n.m. Creating a simple example dll like you said did work! I used your command with a simple HelloWorld.cxx and there were no errors. The problem must be with the Hello_World_wrap.cxx because as soon as I add this file the compilation/linking won't work anymore.

Comment: I tried your Hello_World_wrap.cxx and the only unresolved reference I've got is ``helloWorld[abi:cxx11]()` (which is indeed not defined anywhere). But I have to comment out two directives `#include "Foo/HelloWorld/...` because I don't have these files. Are you absolutely sure you are using the exact commands you show in your post?  It very much looks like compiling and linking are done by two different installs of gcc.

Comment: Yes, I used exactly those commands. Thanks for your help, but I will try something else. Seems like g++ just isn't for me.

Comment: Try adding "-fPIC"